# Add a negative operator(?) to a class in C#

Tags: c#, operators

I may not be using the right word here and that could be why I can't find the answer on my own.  I have a + & - operator in my class, but I want to add a negative operator... I basicly what to be able to do this:

`myMethod(myClass, -myClass);`

If you need code examples to help me out let me know, but I think this should be pretty strait forward... Or that it can't be done.

Comment: What is this negative operator supposed to do?

Comment: Are you thinking of the [logical negation operator `!`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If you're overloading the unary minus operator it would be a good practice to also overload the unary plus operator as well. It's the world's most useless operator, I know, but it is also odd to be able to say `-foo` and not `+foo`.

Comment: Just because you can - dosn't mean you should. Why would you wanna do that?

Comment: I agree with the others that this has a code smell to it. Why the desire to do this?

Comment: My class contains 3 variables, all integers.  Currently when I want to create a negative value I do: `new myClass(-thisInst.int1, -thisInst.int2, -thisInst.int3);` -- having a negative operator makes since here because it is just flipping the signs.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that managed DirectX defines `Vector3` as a `struct` rather than a `class`. You may wish to consider this for your implementation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sure, the unary `-` operator [is overloadable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public static MyClass operator -(MyClass myClass)
{
    ...
}
```

Be careful not to abuse these features as consumers may be unaware of the semantics of these operators - unlike methods (which can be well-named), it is often not immediately obvious what a custom operator on a type does. Hopefully, your class represents a vector of some sort or similar?

Comment: Awesome... But now I feel dumb.  I should have figured that out; didn't even think about creating the operator with only 1 parameter.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks also for the extra tips. It's a class that contains a set of 3 integers; So the negative would just flip the sign of those values.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static YourClass operator -(YourClass value)
{
}
```